# Charles Bukowski's poem about waking up every morning and trying to be a poet/writer

Tags: identification-request, poetry, charles-bukowski

I tried to google it, I searched in libraries and can't find it. But 15 years ago I read a poem by Charles Bukowski where he describes how every morning he wakes up and tries to be a poet/writer. Any Bukowski fans that can help me find it?

Comment: ["Roll the dice"](https://www.poeticous.com/charles-bukowski/roll-the-dice)? It's not specifically about being a poet, it's just about giving one's all to any endeavor.